# Prevent mongoose OverwriteModelError in NextJs Typescript without losing the types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mongoose, next.js

I know, some of you will solve this issue with the following code.

```
const TodoModel = mongoose.models.Todo ?? mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

But this implementation will lose the types/auto-complete of the model as shown below.
[image]

Basically, I want to preserve the autocomplete provided by Typesript as shown below.
[image]

Additionally, if you declare a `static` methods in the schema just like below, typescript will auto-complete the static methods for you.

[image]
[image]

But if you do the `||` or `??` (Nullish coalescing operator), you won't have the intellisense